# Link Helper Class in ASP.Net MVC; Where is the URL-Encode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5

To get the URL's I wanted i created a simple Link Creator helper for my search results.
But it wont let me use server urlencode in it and some of the details passed are French/Czech/Swedish words commas and apostrophes;

Is there a quick function that will strip all this garbage out before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom HTML helper for this. Generate HTML markup using TagBuilder and use UrlEncode where you want. For example:

```
public static string SearchActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues)
{
    var innerHtml = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode("....");

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a") {
        InnerHtml = innerHtml;
    };

    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, routeValues);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

    return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

Something like this?:

```
public static string SearchActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    var ref = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(routeValues["ref"]);
    routeValues["ref"] = "_REF_";

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = linkText; };

    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var url = urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeValues).Replace("_REF_", ref);

    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

    return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Comment: Ta, technically though I wouldn't want to url encode the label <a>LABEL</a> and InnerHtml = innerHtml shouldn't have the semi-colon.

The only problem with this is that it produces links /routevalues/action/

Comment: You can use any `Url.Action` or `Url.RouteUrl` you want or maybe I misunderstand you question :) Where is the problem with `UrlEncode` exactly?

Comment: My URL's are like this: /companies/city/town/ref <ref is the ID.
Some of the Cities/Towns contain dodgy characters (For a uri) like ,'&. - the most problematic seemed to be the period which was killing the string, but I need to preserve as much of the url as possible as its string matched in a linq query on the details page to produce the full details.

I couldn't actually get urlencode on the page originally as I'm used to it being under Server.UrlEncode.
I've used most of it bar the URLHelper which i replaced with
URL = var url = String.Format("/companies/{0}/{1}/{2}",cty,twn,cmp);

Comment: Bastard site killed my comment :|  .
Links as above i changed the URLHelper bit to  
var url = String.Format("/companies/{0}/{1}/{2}", city, town,ref);

I couldn't find the urlencode before (its usually server.urlencode). And some of the town names contain ,&éú. the period being the one that caused problems but i need it all to string match it in a linq query on the other side

Comment: Instead of: html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode couldn't you use: HttpUtility.UrlEncode?